# Setting options in animateWithDuration in Swift 2

Tags: uiview, swift2, animatewithduration

I am animating a textfield with the following code:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.4,
        options: .Repeat | .Autoreverse | .CurveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.password.center.x += self.view.bounds.width
        }, completion: nil)
```

I get the error `Could not find member 'Repeat'`

The code only works if I set only one option. **Why is it not letting me set multiple options?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The syntax for combining `OptionSetType` has changed, you will be able to do it like this:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.4,
    options: [.Repeat, .CurveEaseOut, .Autoreverse], animations: {
        self.password.center.x += self.view.bounds.width
    }, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Where did you find this?

Comment: The docs for `UIViewAnimationOptions` show that it conforms to the `OptionSetType` protocol. The docs for `OptionSetType` have a really nice example on how to combine options. You can also command-click `UIViewAnimationOptions` in Xcode, then cmd-click `OptionSetType` to see the same example code as the docs.